# How to construct a nested dictionary while taking user input?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

**Problem**

I want to construct a nested dictionar with user entering key and values in Python.
Below is an example of the dictionary.

```
dict = {series_name: {char_name: wishlist}}
```

Here **series_name** , **char_name** and **wishlist** is entered by the user.
Also user can add multiple **char_name** for particular series.

**Example**

```
dict = {'naruto': {'itachi': 200, 'hinata': 100}, 'one piece': {'monkey': 1000, 'zoro': 1023}}
```

Comment: How you construct the dictionary is irrelevant. You can convert a `dict` to JSON with the `json` module. `json_str = json.dumps(YOURDICT)`

Comment: Sorry my bad constructing the dictionary was my question. Converting I know with json.dump()

Comment: So you want us to show you how to create a system that turns user input into a nested `dict`? I believe that is beyond the scope of this site. We're here to help you fix your code ... not design it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got bored and came up with a possible solution. Due to my use of a walrus (`:=`) you will need at least python 3.8 for this code to run. Explanations are in the comments.

```
import json

entries = dict() #represents a database of all current entries

def entry():
    global entries
    
    series   = input("Input Series: ")
    name     = []
    wishlist = []
    
    #allows the user to add as many items as they like
    #terminate this process by sending an empty line
    while not ((n := input("Input Character Name or Press Return to Skip: ")) == ""):
        name.append(n)
        wishlist.append(input("Input Wishlist: "))
    
    #create the series if it doesn't exist
    if series not in entries:
        entries[series] = dict()
        
    #create the entries if they don't exist
    for n, w in zip(name, wishlist):
        if not n in entries[series]:
            entries[series][n] = w
        
    
entry()
  
print(json.dumps(entries))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for the json part you can use the module json. As for the rest, you would need to do a thing like that:

```
my_series = dict()
stop_first = False
while not stop_first:
    series_name = input("Name of the series: ")
    if series_name == "None":
        stop_first = True
    else:
        stop_second = False
        my_series[series_name] = dict()
        while not stop_second:
            character_name = input("Name of the character: ")
            if character_name == "None":
                stop_second = True
            else:
                wishlist = int(input("Wishlist: "))
                my_series[series_name][character_name] = wishlist

print(my_series)
```